# Evaluating input function inline, in order to append input or placeholder to a list

Tags: python

I'm having some fun with Python inline functions, and wonder if this is even possible.

I'm using the click module, and I'm using its prompt function and I will add the entered value to a list. However if nothing is entered in the prompt I want to add '** empty **'. Now, Click has a default value, but I'm not putting the value there, because then the prompt will show "Name [** empty **]" instead of "Name []".

So what I thought of doing is this. If the prompt returns '' (empty) then it should append '** empty **'. I feel like I almost have it. But it just ends of running the code, but appending an empty '' item to the list. Not my text with ' '** empty **'.

So the code looks like this:

```
item = []
    item.append(click.prompt("Name", default = '') if not '' else '** empty **')
```

The way I view it click.prompt() is a function that returns a value. The default = '' should tell it to return '' if nothing is entered. So what I want to achieve is, that if the click.prompt() returns '' then it should append '** empty **' to the list. It just doesn't work. As mentioned it appends ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
item.append(click.prompt("Name", default='') or '** empty **')
```

Your expression was

```
click.prompt("Name", default = '') if not '' else '** empty **'
```

This is the same as:

```
if not '':
    item.append(click.prompt("Name", default=''))
else:
    item.append('** empty **')
```

But `not ''` is always true, because `''` is always false.  So you were always appending the string the user entered, including the empty string.

Comment: Thanks, it sure works. Just of curiosity so I learn this! What IF, I wanted if the prompt returned a value like 0 and that should evaluate to empty?

Comment: I guess it would be: item.append(click.prompt(“Name”, default = '') if not 0 else '** empty **')

Comment: Actually this puzzles me. (It works for me your answer) Now I just try to play with it. Like how would I, without calling the function twice, look for the input 'No' and make that '\*\* empty \*\*'. Then I would want to item.append(click.prompt("Name", default='') if != 'No' else '\*\* empty \*\*') ... however it misses the click.prompt value between if and !=. But I don't think i can pour the click.prompt into a variable inline can I? Like item.append(x = click.prompt("Name", default='') if x != 'No' else '** empty **')  .. I know it's f'ed up, and it also fails.

Answer (score 0):

@Ned's solution is the best:

```
item.append(click.prompt("Name", default='') or '** empty **')
```

Or to do something that's kind of similar to what you did:

```
c=click.prompt("Name", default = '')
item.append(c if c else '** empty **')
```

Or of course can do, (but runs `click.prompt("Name", default = '')` twice, so better just once):

```
item.append(click.prompt("Name", default = '') if click.prompt("Name", default = '') else '** empty **')
```

Comment: Cool, I think you just answered the comment I made on Neds solution.

Comment: @InspectorBootsector Happy that i helped,

Comment: @InspectorBootsector can upvote me and Ned, when you get 15 reputation

Comment: Ill do that. Thanks