# Inline function with if/else: check returned value and append to list on condition, without calling function twice

Tags: python

This one is hard to word. It comes from trying to understand inline functions.

This question is a spin-off of another question I asked: [Evaluating input function inline, in order to append input or placeholder to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349830/evaluating-input-function-inline-in-order-to-append-input-or-placeholder-to-a-l)

I want this code to work. The idea is, to evaluate the output of a function without calling it twice - and the choice should be appended to the list if it is equal to a set value:

```
import random

def returner():
    choices = ['cat', 'dog']
    return random.choice(choices)

list = []
list.append(returner() if returner() == 'dog' else 'got the cat in the bag')
```

The thing is, above I called the function twice. If it was a user input, it wouldn't be so great, to prompt the user twice. So I thought I could do:

```
list.append(x = returner() if x == 'dog' else 'got the cat in the bag')
```

Is it possible to do something like above?

Comment: This is a great example that one-liners are not always the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what you are comparing it against you could do

```
list = []
list.append("dog" if returner() == "dog" else "got cat in the bag")
```

otherwise you will have to do

```
list = []
r = returner()
list.append(r if r == 'dog' else 'got the cat in the bag')
```

in either case, you can actually make your code even more compact by changing these two lines

```
list = []
list.append("dog" if returner() == "dog" else "got cat in the bag")
```

into

```
list = ["dog" if returner() == "dog" else "got cat in the bag"]
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer. I think I'm overcomplicating things trying to make everything happen in a single line. Thanks for the examples. It's example two I'll go with for future reference. :)

Comment: I didn't even notice this, I was using the same variable names as OP, but yes you are very correct, it is a bad idea to overwrite `list`

Answer (score 1):

You can defer the calling of `returner()` and put its result in a (1-element) list, that you can use:

```
import random

def returner():
    choices = ['cat', 'dog']
    return random.choice(choices)

l = [x if x == "dog" else 'got the cat in the bag' for x in [returner()] ]
print(l)
```

but I would be hesitent to do so - the approach of storing the (one) result of it beforehand is cleaner:

```
choi = returner()
l = [choi if choi == "dog" else 'got the cat in the bag' ]
```

However if you need multiples, the first approach woud work:

```
l = [x if x == "dog" else 'got the cat in the bag' 
     for x in [returner() for _ in range(20)] ]
```